# Laravel API routes 404 error using Heroku Apache

Tags: laravel, apache, heroku

I am setting up my Laravel API on Heroku. Everything seems to be working fine, I am able to go to the site and see the Laravel public page. But when I try to access my API routes (signup, login, etc.), it returns a 404 error.

The routes work fine on my own virtual hosts that I created but once I uploaded it to Heroku, all the routes except for "/" return 404. I've checked to see if "index.php/" would work but still returns a 404.

public/htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} 1^public
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Procfile

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/
```

routes/api.php

```
$api = app('Dingo\Api\Routing\Router');
$api->version("v1", function ($api) {
    $api->get("/", function () {
        return response()->json([
            'status' => 'success'
        ], 200);
    });

    $api->post("/signup", "MusicShare\Http\Controllers\AuthController@signup");
})
```

Heroku logs

```
2019-06-16T23:04:37.778061+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.35.223.16 - - [16/Jun/2019:23:04:37 +0000] "GET /index.php/routes HTTP/1.1" 200 47843 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.80 Safari/537.36
```

My Heroku logs do not return an error. Everything shows the status code as 200 but I still get a 404 in Chrome if I try to access "/api/signup" or "/signup" or "/index.php/signup"

Answer (score 2):

if you are using apache `LAMP` server try this code

go to the conf file and edit this

i am using `//` for comminting for you

`ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    <Directory "/var/www/html"> // here you project path 
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All // alow all permissions
        Require all granted
    </Directory>`

and server restart

for this command `sudo service apache2 restart`

then try this command for rewrite
`sudo a2enmod rewrite`

and your sub routes working perfictlly

dont't forgot this command `sudo a2enmod rewrite`

Comment: I used Heroku CLI to set this up, I'm not using a LAMP server.

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit the config vars --- added API_PREFIX and API_DOMAIN into the Heroku settings for my site.